# Possible to have Spring @RequestBody and HttpEntity at the same time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-boot-actuator

I have the following code in my Spring Boot app:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/execute")
public class RestCommandExecutor {

  @PostMapping
  public Response executeCommand(@RequestBody Command command, 
                                 HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) {
    System.out.println(command);
    System.out.println("********* payload is: " + httpEntity.getBody());

    return new Response("Hello text", new Long(123));
  }
}
```

When a POST request comes in with the proper `Command`, I get an I/O error:

`.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed`

I'd like Spring to translate the request body into `Command`, but since the JSON holds more than what is part of the `Command` class, I'd like to get the full JSON in raw as well.

Is there a way to achieve this through mapping in the method? I know I can always do this `public Response executeCommand(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity)` and then manually translate it into `Command` using Jackson, but I would rather not have to do that manually.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why you want to convert it into Command?

Comment: To retrieve its `type` property. Then, I'd deserialize it into a type that would translate all of the command's properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can’t both read the `HttpEntity`’s body and use `@RequestBody` is that both read from the `HttpRequest`’s `InputStream` and close it afterwards. Since you can’t read again from the `InputStream` after it’s closed, the last operation fails as you see.

It seems what you actually want is to access some properties that aren’t mapped in the `Command` class, particularly into a class specified using a `type` property.
You can do this using Jackson’s `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubtype` annotations, which allow you customize the deserialization for a class hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That does make sense. I can't use your suggestion as I don't know (upfront) what types could be coming, but nevertheless.